# Where can I find this kind of line graph?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have this data gave to me in excel spreadsheet

```
2017                    2018            
Month   Sales   TC  TA      Month   Sales   TC  TA
Jan -0.08   -0.08   0       Jan 0.02    0   0.02
Feb -0.06   -0.08   0.02        Feb 0.01    -0.03   0.05
Mar -0.06   -0.07   0.01        Mar 0.06    0   0.06
Apr -0.07   -0.09   0.02        Apr 0.01    -0.02   0.03
May -0.04   -0.03   0       May 0.01    -0.04   0.05
Jun -0.04   -0.02   -0.02       Jun 0.03    -0.05   0.08
Jul 0.05    0.04    0.01        Jul -0.03   -0.05   0.03
Aug -0.03   -0.02   -0.01       Aug -0.02   -0.06   0.05
Sep -0.02   -0.02   -0.01       Sep -0.01   -0.05   0.04
Oct 0.03    0.01    0.02        Oct         
Nov 0.08    0.03    0.05        Nov         
Dec 0.11    0.07    0.04        Dec
```

And they want this kind of line graph, where can I find this kind of line graph.
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to taker the raw data provided and create the graph?  So, your asking what is the process to turn data into graphs ?

Comment: No, I can turn it into graph. I just want to know what kind of graph is that because I can't find online i'm not familiar of those graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)  Align your data so that the data makes one continuous column.  Basically copy the 2018 data and place it under the 2017 data.  It should look like the following:

[image: Aligned data]

2)  Select your range of data:

[image: Data range]

(Note the header row was included in this case to automatically give names to each of your series)

3)  From the Insert ribbon select insert line graph.  Pick the line type graph that suits your needs.

[image: Pick-a-Graph]

4)  Manually create boxes with rounded corners to separate your years if you want the boxes in the picture.  From the insert ribbon select shapes then select the box with the rounded corners.  Draw your box.  Then edit its properties so that the fill colour is none, and adjust the outline to colour of your choice and adjust its line weight.  When you have completed one box, simply cut and paste it back in to keep the same size and settings.  Move the pasted boxes to the appropriate location.  To add the year to the boxes, insert a text box and type it in.

[image: Manual Text Shapes added]

Comment: Wow, good effort. I was just going to say, it's a line chart overlaid with some rounded rectangles.